# Dotnet core 3.1 version of RelationalMetadataExtensions.Relations()

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We are reading relational database specific metadata using **RelationalMetadataExtensions** in dotnet core 2.0. We have planned to upgrade the app into 3.0. But **RelationalMetadataExtensions** is obsolute in the dotnet core 3.0. What will be the dotnet core 3.1 behavior of the following code

```
  // Following code only working for mysql.
        var items = _context.Model.GetEntityTypes();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            //RelationalMetadataExtensions.Relational([NotNullAttribute] this IEntityType entityType)
            if (item.Relational() is RelationalEntityTypeAnnotations extensions)
            {
                extensions.Schema = database;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on [the update log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#metadata-api-changes), your code will not work. You will need to use the flattened out versions.

Unfortunately, the [issue 214](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/214) seems to still be open. I can see the [GetSchema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypeextensions.getschema?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalEntityTypeExtensions_GetSchema_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IEntityType_) has been implemented already, but no SetSchema to be found. You could raise a new GitHub request to see when (if) it's getting there

**Edit**

There is a SetSchema [check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypeextensions.setschema?view=efcore-3.1). Kudos to Ivan Stoev.

> Provider-specific Metadata API changes
>
> Tracking Issue #214
>
> New behavior
>
> The provider-specific extension methods will be flattened out:
>
> `IProperty.Relational().ColumnName -> IProperty.GetColumnName()`
>   `IEntityType.SqlServer().IsMemoryOptimized -> IEntityType.IsMemoryOptimized()`
>   `PropertyBuilder.UseSqlServerIdentityColumn() -> PropertyBuilder.UseIdentityColumn()`
>
> **Why**
>
> This change simplifies the implementation of the aforementioned extension methods.
>
> Mitigations
>
> Use the new extension methods.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypeextensions.setschema?view=efcore-3.1

Comment: Nice, I did not spot this one. I will update answer accordingly